# WPF Validating TextBox in an outside library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

what I am trying to do is somewhat out there, and I have yet to really see an example of this.

I am trying to validate a textbox entry that is essentially a required field (it cannot be null or empty). However, I do not have any access to the code behind, only to the XAML and data binding for the form.

From searching for a couple of days, I found out this cannot be done strictly in XAML (which would have been preferred), and had to create my own resource library to check for this. That is what I have done, but failed to get it to work.

Is this even a possibility? Or what would I have to do to get this to work?

What I have done so far was create a usercontrol template of a textbox to then use in the XAML (residing in an outside library):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel x:Name="dpMain" LastChildFill="True">
        <Label/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace ClassLibrary.CustomControls
{

public partial class CssTextBox : UserControl
{
    private TextBox _textbox = null;
    private ObservableCollection<ValidationRule> _validationRules = null;

    public CssTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateControls();
        ValidationRules = new ObservableCollection<ValidationRule>();
        this.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(CssTextBoxDataChanged);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ValidationRule> ValidationRules
    {
        get { return _validationRules; }
        set { _validationRules = value; }
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        _textbox = new TextBox() { Width = 100, Height = 20 };
        _textbox.LostFocus += CssTextBoxLostFocus;
        _textbox.Style = TextBoxErrorStyle;
    }

    public void CssTextBoxDataChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_textbox != null)
        {
            var binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = this.DataContext;
            binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            binding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;

            foreach (var rule in ValidationRules)
            {
                binding.ValidationRules.Add(rule);
            }

            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(BoundPropertyName);
            _textbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

            dpMain.Children.Add(_textbox);
        }
    }

    public void CssTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingExpression = _textbox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (bindingExpression != null)
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
    }

    private Style TextBoxErrorStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (Style)FindResource("TextBoxStyle");
        }
    }

    public string TextBoxErrorStyleName { get; set; }
    public string BoundPropertyName { get; set; }
    public string ValidationExpression { get; set; }
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _textbox.Text;
        }

    }

    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

And how it is being used (currently being tested in a WPF Sandbox project and only being referenced via XAML):

```
xmlns:css="clr-namespace:WpfSandbox.CustomControls" <!--Reference to library that holds above--!>


    <css:CssTextBox TextBoxErrorStyleName="TextBoxStyle" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <css:CssTextBox.ValidationRules>
            <validators:NotNullOrEmptyValidationRule ErrorMessage="Cannot be Empty!" />
        </css:CssTextBox.ValidationRules>
    </css:CssTextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Width="auto" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

My issue with what I have now, is that it shows the textbox in my designer window in my sandbox application, but I cannot click into it when I run. It's almost like it does not exist.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score -1):

You should read about WPF Data validation.
This link will help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx